# Managing ECS Revisions with Terraform and CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I use Terraform to manage infrastructure and CodeDeploy to rollout the ECS service. I'm wondering if there's a best practice on preventing Terraform from incrementing the version of revision of the ECS image in order to allow CodeDeploy to roll out changes.

I believe if I `terraform apply` it will apply the revision immediately that the service is using, correct? I would like to have CodeDeploy manage the rollout of the service but also keep Terraform to manage infrastructure.

**Edit**

I'm wondering if the best use case would be to use something like:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html
and bypass version changes

Example:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [task_definition]
  }
```

Comment: Your edit pretty much sums up the best way to have Terraform ignore something. Did it work for you? If not it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a [mcve] that can be ran to show your problem and explain the steps that would happen outside of Terraform's context.

Comment: It did work for me. Unfortunately, I didn't have a great way to break out the changes into a reproducible script. I appreciate the response though and yet it doesn't force a deployment change because I've tested it a few times.